# Use NotebookWrite with Graphics?

Tags: graphics, notebooks

I am trying to use NotebookWrite to paste a plot into another notebook. The code looks something like:

`ptemp = Show[Plot[x^2,{x,-2,2}],Plot[x^3,{x,-2,2}]];
nb = CreateDocument[];
NotebookWrite[nb,ptemp];`

But when I run the code I get an error message: `An unknown box name (Graphics) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression.`

Is there any way to use NotebookWrite to insert a graphic? Does there exist any sort of wrapper for Graphics that would make it NotebookWrite-able?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use :
      `NotebookWrite[nb, ToBoxes[ptemp]]`

With `NotebookWrite[]`, you must use [boxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RepresentingTextualFormsByBoxes.html) ("low-level-box-language"), not Graphics (which belongs to normal Mathematica language, like nearly everything). The "box-language" is what you see when you type ctrl-shift-E on a cell. `ToBoxes` transforms `pTemp` to a box. `NotebookWrite[]` inserts automatically the data (the box) in a  `Cell[]` (see doc) and inserts the `Cell[..data..]` in the notebook.

Comment: +1, and it's good to note explicitly that this applies to everything, not just graphics.  Everything needs to be converted to [boxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RepresentingTextualFormsByBoxes.html) before using them in NotebookWrite.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. I have improved my answer. Hope it's clear.