# How to write Boxes to a notebook with NotebookWrite?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, contexts

I would like to write Boxes to a Cell to a notebook (e.g., FractionBox, SuperscriptBox, etc).

Here is what I've tried:

```
nbTarget = 
  CreateDocument[{},
   NotebookFileName -> "Target", 
   WindowSize -> {1411, 753}, 
   ScrollingOptions -> {"PageWiseDisplay" -> True}];

NotebookWrite[nbTarget, Cell[" ", "Text"]]

SelectionMove[nbTarget, Previous, Cell]

SelectionMove[nbTarget, After, CellContents]
```

Works in this case,

```
NotebookWrite[nbTarget, FractionBox["a", "b"]]
```

But doesn't work if a and b are Symbols, a and b are in $CellContext

```
Clear[a,b];
NotebookWrite[nbTarget, FractionBox[a, b]]}]
```

Try to force evaluation, doesn't work

```
NotebookWrite[nbTarget, 
 With[{disp = FractionBox[a, b]]}, disp]]
```

Try DisplayForm, doesn't work.

```
NotebookWrite[nbTarget, 
 With[{disp = DisplayForm[FractionBox[a, b]]}, disp]]
```

RawBoxes doesn't work:

```
NotebookWrite[nbTarget, RawBoxes@FractionBox[a, b]]
```

Comment: `FractionBox[a, b]` is not valid box syntax. A symbol is not a valid box object.

Comment: What do you expect `FractionBox[a, b]` to be or look like? Take a look at the output of `a / b` with Ctrl+Shift+E.

Comment: Thanks @Kuba, I can't remember now.  I now understand boxes a bit better.  I think that--at the time--I wanted FractionBox[1+a,1+b] to look like `BoxData[
 FractionBox[
  RowBox[{"1", "+", "a"}], 
  RowBox[{"2", "+", "b"}]]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first note :  I have simplified your question. There's no need to create a new document to play with the problem. Hence I use NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[]...] instead of NotebookWrite[nbTarget ...]

So, your problem is that :

```
Clear[a, b];
NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], FractionBox[a, b]]
```

gives :
[image]

and not :

[image]

This is because the low-level "Box language"  only accepts as parameters Strings and other xxxBox. What you want to do is certainly :

```
Clear[a, b];
NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], FractionBox["a", "b"]]
```

[image]

For such problem, it is more convenient to create the fraction in the 2D typesseting form and apply MakeBoxes on it to have it in the Box language :

[image]

[image]

[image]

> FractionBox["a", "b"]

The box language is nearly not documented. There are a lot of informations in Jason Harris's Videos called "typesetting"(Wolfram Technology conference). But It's not trivial.

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24116/5467)

Comment: This is very clear now:  "This is because the low-level "Box language" only accepts as parameters Strings and other xxxBox. "  Thanks for looking back at older questions.

Answer (score 1):

Paste seems to work with DisplayForm, I wish I knew **why** it works.

Paste[nbTarget, DisplayForm@FractionBox[a, b]]

Comment: DisplayForm tries to convert badly formed boxes into a valid boxes. I don't like this function, I think it is better to just create proper boxes in the first place, instead of relying on the heuristics in DisplayForm to fix your mistakes.

Comment: Thank you @CarlWoll, can you point me to a place in the documentation where I can learn to create proper boxes?  Perhaps my confusion comes from not understanding Boxes at a more fundamental level.

Comment: I don't know if there is anything in the documentation about the proper syntax for boxes. I think that for the most part, a valid syntax for boxes includes only the symbols *Box and strings, although options are usually just expressions. One way to learn about the syntax of boxes is to use MakeBoxes on various expressions to see what they look like.